# I am learning Python, need some pushing in the right direction

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python through Coursera, and have some questions about an assignment.

> Write a program that prompts for a file name, then opens that file and reads through the file, looking for lines of the form:
>
> ```
> X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475
> ```
>
> Count these lines and extract the floating point values from each of the lines and compute the average of those values and produce an output as shown below. Do not use the `sum()` function or a variable named `sum` in your solution.

My code so far is as follows:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
f = open(fname)
for line in f:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    print line   
print "Done"
```

I am a bit confused. Should I store each line I get into a file or variable or something and then extract the floating point values for each?
How should this be tackled in the simplest way since this is just the beginning of the course?

Comment: This isn't a tutorial site, but keep doing what you're doing. Should you keep the values somewhere?  Probably, if you intend to use them. :)

Comment: You don't need to store lines. Read line, extract value and save it. There is no point in elaborating "simplest way" for 2 minute task that can be done in 300 ways.

Comment: ... why is coursera still providing courses for a python version that is 6 years old? If you are just starting python I suggest you learn python3.x and not python2.x...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that suffices your work. I am reading the float values from the line with "X-DSPAM-Confidence:" and adding them and in the end, I am taking the mean. Also, since you are a beginner, I suggest to keep in mind that when you are dealing with division and you are expecting a float, either numerator or denominator should be float to give the answer in float. Since in the below code snippet, our number is float, we wont have that issue.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
f = open(fname)
cnt = 0
mean_val = 0
for line in f:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    mean_val += float(line.split(':')[1])
    cnt += 1
f.close()
mean_val /= cnt
print mean_val
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the replies.  I wanted a push, into the right direction, as in maybe a plan on what should be implemented.  But thanks for just showing me ways of doing all this.

Comment: How ever I do have a question, how are the += and /=  working in python. i have no idea what they do

Comment: a=a+b and a=a/b can be simply written as a+=b and a/=b

Answer (score 1):

The reason not to use a variable named `sum` is because there is a function with the same name.

The assignment asks you to do the work of the `sum()` function explicitly.  You are on the right track with the `if not` line but might be more successful if you reverse the logic (like this: `if line.startswith` ...), then put the handling inside an indented block that follows.

The handling you need is to keep track of how many such lines you handle and the accumulated sum.  Use a term that is a synonym for `sum` that is not already a Python identifier.  Extract the float value from the end of `line` and then `<your sum variable> += float(the float from "line")`.

Don't forget to initialize both counter and accumulator before the loop.

Comment: Extract the float value from the end of ``line``:  ``float(line.split()[-1])``

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(fname) as f:
    s = 0
    linecount = 0
    for line in f:
        l = line.split()
        try:
            num = float(l[1])
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if l[0] == 'X-DSPAM-Confidence:':
            s += num
            linecount += 1
    print(s/linecount)
```

Here's how I would do it.  I'll happily answer any questions.

Comment: True.  it's force of habit really, I'm used to splitting on characters that aren't whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Regular expression**.

[More info regarding re module, check here !!!](https://pymotw.com/2/re/)

**Code:**

```
import re
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
f = open(fname)
val_list = []
tot = 0
line_cnt = 0
for line in f:
  a = re.findall("X-DSPAM-Confidence:\s*(\d+\.?\d*)",line)
  if len(a) != 0:
    tot += float(a[0])
    line_cnt +=1

print ("Line Count is ",line_cnt)
print ("Average is ",tot/line_cnt)
f.close()
```

**Content of y.txt:**

```
a
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475
b
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8476
c
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8477
d
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8478
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Enter file name: y.txt
Line Count is  4
Average is  0.84765

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

**Points:**

- *You can open file using `with` as Patrick has done in his answer. If file is opened using `with` then no need to close the file explicit.*

Comment: ```re``` seems like massive overkill for this example. Given the OP is only learning Python you want to make them learn regular expressions just to do this simple task? He is given the exact string the interesting lines start with. Simpler should be much better. That or at least describe the regex string you suggest?